# ExtJs Window AutoScroll not working

Tags: extjs, window, scroll

My Window has 2 objects: a gridPanel and a formPanel. The formPanel is always on display and the gridPanel (which sits above it) is only shown on occasion.

The issue I'm having is that autoScroll is not working at all.

```
#Window Config#
UserSelection = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
id: 'comWin',
title: 'User Selection',
width: 700,
height: 300,   
autoScroll: true,
maximizable: true,
autoDestroy: false,
closeAction: 'hide'

#Items added to config at creation#
this.add(comGrid);            
this.add(comForm);

#When Grid is shown#
comGrid.show();
comWin.doLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

autoScroll is just a CSS wrapper on overflow: auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/HpDAm/ in this example code changing autoScroll to true/false will show/hide scrollbars.

Comment: As you can see from my code autoScroll is set to true yet the scrollbars don't appear.